# Do the statistics shown on Area 51 include closed questions?

Tags: support, area-51, statistics, beta-phase

Does Area 51 also include closed questions in its statistics?

For example, is the number of answers per question reported for a site in beta influenced by closed questions, or are those questions not considered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use numbers returned by the public /stats api, e.g. http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.1/stats:

```
answeredPercentage = 100 - (total_unanswered / total_questions * 100);
answerRatio = total_answers / (total_questions * answeredPercentage / 100);
```

But slightly confusingly, the api's return values for `total_questions` and `total_answers` include closed questions, but `total_unanswered` doesn't.

So, `answeredPercentage` ("% answered" on the stats page) is actually "percentage of questions that have been resolved" ...either by an answer or by closing.