# How is the "percent answered" rate calculated for a site on the StackExchange.com site list?

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, unanswered-questions, answered-questions

The "%answered rate" of all Stack Exchange sites are mentioned on https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic:

> [image: The site row for the Software Recommendations site on StackExchange.com/sites]

Can someone please explain how is the exact percentage is calculated for any particular site?

For example, I have a local database containing the June 2023 data dump for the Software Recommendations site. It contains a total of 22,436 questions, which I calculated using the following query:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
  FROM [SoftwareRecommendationsPostsDb_June2023].[dbo].[SoftwareRecommendationsPosts]
  where PostTypeId =1
```

The total questions with an accepted answer is 4,823 (lets call them successful-Qs):

```sql
SELECT count(*)
  FROM [SoftwareRecommendationsPostsDb_June2023].[dbo].[SoftwareRecommendationsPosts]
  where PostTypeId =1 and AcceptedAnswerId !=0
```

Those with at least one answer but no accepted answer are 8,647 (lets call them semi-successful-Qs):

```sql
SELECT count(*)
  FROM [SoftwareRecommendationsPostsDb_June2023].[dbo].[SoftwareRecommendationsPosts]
  where PostTypeId =1 and AnswerCount >0 and AcceptedAnswerId =0
```

Those without any answer (accepted or unaccepted) are 8,966 (lets call them unsuccessful-Qs):

```sql
SELECT count(*)
  FROM [SoftwareRecommendationsPostsDb_June2023].[dbo].[SoftwareRecommendationsPosts]
  where PostTypeId =1 and AnswerCount =0
```

The total number of questions must equal the sum of the three categories above, so
`Total Qs = successful-Qs + semi-successful-Qs + unsuccessful-Qs`;
22,436  = 4,823 + 8,647 + 8,966.

Now when I try to calculate the %answered rate, I get a different number than the one presented on https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic, which leaves me confused about how this number is being calculated.

If the %answered rate is calculated by:
%answered rate = [(Qs with some answer either accepted or not)/total Qs ]*100
%answered rate = [(successful-Qs + semi-successful-Qs )/total Qs ]*100
%answered rate = [(4823 + 8647 )/22436  ]*100
%answered rate = 60.04%

Is the 54% value provided as site statistic incorrect, or am I missing something in the calculation or doing it incorrectly?

Comment: This question is not clear and badly formatted. I would have edited, if I would understand what you're trying to ask. All the queries appear to be noise that hide the actual question, but honestly I don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had to do a little digging to track this one down, since I found a fair amount of misconception floating around this number. According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289684) by user [@Mariano](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/304899/mariano) to a question asking about the %Answered metric used over on Area51, the missing piece to your calculations is *question closure*.

@Mariano's answer [cites another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86976), written by a former Stack Exchange developer, which states that **the metric considers closed questions as resolved/ "answered"**.

That means the "answered" number contains 3 types of questions:

1. Questions with an accepted answer
2. Questions with ≥1 upvoted answer
3. Closed questions

Or, as described by @Mariano:

> Where `Answered = AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed`.
> And then `%Answered = 100 * Answered / Asked`.

---

Both of those questions were about *Area51's* %Answered metric though, which I wasn't sure was the same at first. We can confirm it's the same though by checking the number ourselves with [the SEDE query provided by @Mariano](https://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/530265/percent-answered-in-se-sites-or-answered-in-area51-statistics) and comparing it to what's listed on the Sites page:

```sql
WITH Answers AS (
  -- unique answers with best score per question
  SELECT ParentId AS Id, MAX(Score) AS Score
  FROM Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId = 2
  GROUP BY ParentId
)
, Counts AS (
  SELECT
    -- Count for questions joined with answers
    COUNT(*) AS Asked,
    SUM(IIF(Q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL AND Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS AcceptedNotClosed,
    SUM(IIF(Q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL AND A.Score > 0 AND Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 1, 0))
      AS PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed,
    SUM(IIF(Q.ClosedDate IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS Closed
  FROM Posts Q
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers A
    ON Q.Id = A.Id
  WHERE Q.PostTypeId = 1
)
  
SELECT 
  Asked, AcceptedNotClosed, PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed, Closed,
  (AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed) AS Answered,
  
  Cast(Cast(
    (AcceptedNotClosed + PositiveScoreNotAcceptedNotClosed + Closed)
    / CAST(Asked AS FLOAT)
    *100 as decimal(18,2)
  ) as varchar(5)) + ' %' AS "%Answered"
FROM Counts
```

Here's what the query pulls for Software Recommendations:

| Asked | Accepted NotClosed | PositiveScore NotAccepted NotClosed | Closed | Answered | Unanswered | %Answered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22,516 | 4,688 | 6,947 | 547 | 12,182 | 10,334 | **54.10%** |

Taking that 54.10% and comparing that to the Sites page confirms this is indeed the correct (rounded) calculation:

> [image: Software Recommendations listing from the StackExchange.com site list, with the "54% answered" metric highlighted]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Exactly what i was looking for.