# What does '100% answered' mean in 'Today's Featured Site'?

Tags: support, featured-site

Today's featured site is [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) and the card is shown as follows:

[image]

RPG clearly has [unanswered questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=unanswered&pagesize=50).

What is meant by the '*100% answered*'?

Comment: There are 36031 questions on that site.  That means that 99.628% are answered. Rounded to the nearest integer, that would be 100%

Comment: May I just congratulate you lot on this about-as-perfect-as-it-gets score? Staying above 95% is not easy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That means that (rounded towards the nearest whole number) 100% of the non-closed questions have an upvoted or accepted answer. The figure is the same as displayed on the [list of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered).

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86976/295232) by a former Stack Exchange developer, the number is coming from the [`/stats` API call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=default&site=rpg&run=true) which returns 134, exactly the number of [questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=unanswered&pagesize=50)  right now.

<sub>(Since those numbers will change in the future: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191001093349/https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=unanswered&pagesize=50) is an archived link to the Unanswered tab and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20191001093424/https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=rpg) is one with the API call.)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

At Role-Playng Games SE there have been [36,031 questions asked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions).

If I go to its Unanswered tab I can see that [134 questions are unanswered](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=unanswered&pagesize=50).

Dividing 134 by 36,031 and multiplying by 100 gives 0.37% unanswered.  Rounding that to the nearest percent is 0% unanswered or 100% answered.